# PHP: insert html after a specific point

Tags: php, html, insert

I have the following HTML:

```
<aside>
    <p class="opentime">10 - 16</p>
    <p class="clocknote">Hours</p>
</aside>
```

After the *10* and the *16*, I want the following code to be added:

```
<span>00</span>
```

so that it look like this:

```
<aside>
    <p class="opentime">10<span>00</span> - 16<span>00</span></p>
    <p class="clocknote">Hours</p>
</aside>
```

The *span* tag should be inserted after only the *p* tags with the class *opentime*.

Is there any PHP code to make this possible?

---

The actual code which is in the PHP is the following:

```
<?php $main_r_t = $pages->find('response_times/main/') ?>
<?php $r_t = $pages->find('response_times/times.txt') ?>

<aside>
   <p class="opentime"><?php echo $r_t->mo_time_1() ?></p>
   <p class="clocknote"><?php echo $main_r_t->clock() ?></p>
   <p class="opentime"><?php echo $r_t->mo_time_2() ?></p>
   <p class="clocknote"><?php echo $main_r_t->clock() ?></p>
</aside>
```

And the text file looks like:

```
mo_time_1: 10 - 12
----
mo_time_2: 13 - 19
----
```

Comment: How are you generating the HTML at the moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in pure PHP (I have no idea what the capabilities/limitations of Kirby are), you could do something like this:

```
$mo_time = $r_t->mo_time_1();
$time = explode(" - ", $mo_time);
echo "<p class='opentime'>" . $time[0] . "<span>:00</span> - " . $time[1] . "<span>:00</span></p>";
```

This isn't tested and does no error checking... That's up to you :)

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! You only forgot the $ before r_t in the first line :)

Comment: Oh jeez... That's what happens at the end of the day :) Glad it worked for you... You should be able to just use it inside of the `explode()` function to save some memory as well... I just assign it to a variable for readability... `$time = explode(" - ", $r_t->mo_time_1());`

Comment: Can I assign this 3 lines of code to one variable like `<?php echo $time ?>' to not every time write the 3  lines?

Comment: @projektalex you would be much better off writing a function for this and then pass your object to the function, returning the formatted string.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now that it is better to leave some more code but to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
var text = $(".opentime").html();

var splitString = text.split(" ");
var newstr = splitString[0]+"<span>00</span>"+"-"+splitString[1]+"<span>00</span>";

$(".opentime").html(newstr);
```

Comment: Is this possible with php?

Comment: I do not want to use Jquery on all of my sites. I only want to use it for the gallery section.